# Devaney definition of chaos

Tags: chaos-theory

I just started my research on devaney's definition of chaos. I already found proof that on infinite metric space transitivity and dense orbit implies sensitive dependence on initial conditions, on subset of R transitivity implies dense orbit and sensitive dependence on initial condition. I also found on conditions on which transitivity and dense orbit imply each other. Can anyone share artciles/books which i can read to gain more interesting informations? Thanks!